# What is the grammatical function of a list following a colon

Tags: grammar, colons

My ten year old son asked the grammatical function of items in a list following a colon.  Such as the sentence "There are three countries in North America: Canada, The United States, and Mexico."

My first guess was an object complement noun, but "countries" isn't actually a direct object, it's a subject complement for "There". So my current guess is that the entire list is a subject complement, but it's complementing another subject complement. Does anyone have an better explanation or actual reference on this?

Comment: The entire thing _three countries in North America: Canada, USA, and Mexico_ is a noun phrase. The list following the colon is a conjoined noun phrase in apposition with the noun phrase _three countries in North America_. If you want the grammatical function of the entire thing, it's whatever you call a noun phrase that's been moved to the end of a sentence by _There_-Insertion, as in _There is a unicorn in the garden_.

Comment: @JohnLawler that makes sense.  I would call it a predicate nominative.  I used subject complement noun in the original question because it doesn't really make sense to call both phrases a predicate nominative.  An appositive makes sense, though.

Comment: I just realized why I found this so confusing.  All ESL or grade school usage guidance is that this sort of construction can only use a colon after an independent clause, which had me thinking that the list was not part of the main clause.  But that's a useful shortcut to the fact that you need either an object or a subject complement, not an indication that the list isn't part of the main clause.